# View Files from mirrored RAID outside the device

Tags: ubuntu, raid

The Product I have is a [Western Digital My Book](http://www.geek.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/wd_mybook_world_1tb_06.jpg)

The device has stopped working but there is nothing wrong with either of the two mirrored drives. I would like to take out the two mirrored hard drives, and recover the data if at all possible.  How would I go about this on ubuntu 11.10?  Both of the drives are recognized but I can not see the data anywhere. The relevant software I have on the system are: **Disk Utility** and a terminal application called **mdadm**.  I am trying to be cautious and not accidentally wipe the data.  Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you can take out the drive and connected in a different way then you should be able to do:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

Before doing that I would suggest disconnecting the second drive also.

Answer (score 1):

maybe ubuntu allready automounted the devices. you can check that with

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

or by looking for assembles md's:

```
ls /dev/md*
```

if that did not work it depends a bit on how the drives are aligned, but

```
sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sda /dev/sdb
```

should assemble the raid device, and it shouldn't break anything it it doesn't. whereas `/dev/md0` is the ID of the raid device you are creating (you can leave it like this if there are no other raid devices in your system). you just have to exchange `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` with you hdds or partitions (you can raid full hdds or just single partitions). afterwards you can mount the device with

```
sudo mount /dev/md0 /mount/point
```

good luck